# How to write Rest API for the following scenario using mvc layered architecture

Tags: javascript, java, python, node.js

I am new in creating Rest Api. Can anyone help me out how to create Rest Api' for the following operations for my project..

Scenario:
- Get all books that are currently on loan
- Rent a book to card holder

Following is the object structure

Book(Id, title, isbn, author)
cardHolder(id, last name, first name , cardNumber)
Rental(id, cardHolder, Book)

Comment: I am very new in writing api so i wanted to get basic idea of the task mentioned above.. so can you help me out...  Blind Kai

Comment: If you're looking for JavaScript (Node.js) solution, what database and which libraries do you want to use?